# What code can I put in to clear all previous user inputs and re-run the code from the top?

Tags: python, namespaces, interactive, restart

I am currently writing a code that accepts user inputs. However, I intend to put in an option such that if the user made an error, they may restart the process again by typing in a specific input. And I'm hoping that the code clears all previous input from the namespace:

For example

```
name = input("what is your name: ")
age = input("how old are you:? ")
## if the user realizes that they put in the wrong name and wish to restart the process, they may input "restart"
if age == 'restart':
    ### I don't know what code to put here.
else:
    #I'd continue the rest of my codes
```

I'd greatly appreciate any tips.

Comment: What are you using `IDLE` or `cmd`

Comment: This is unclear... Do you mean to ask for the name again in this case? You'll need a loop around this whole piece of code in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Supposedly you want the console to clear if the user decides to change its input in name

```
import os     

while True:
    os.system('clear')   #we imported "os" for this built-in function
    name = input("Enter your name: ")
    age = input("how old are you:? ")

    if age == 'restart': #if user inputs 'restart' we head back to the start of the loop
        input("Press Enter Key to Continue...")
        continue

# Rest of the code goes here
```

Answer (score -2):

You can simple wrap the code in a `while` loop

```py
name = input("what is your name: ")
age = 'restart' # This is simply taking input because of the next line of code

while age == 'restart':
  age = input("how old are you:? ")

# Rest of the code goes here
```

Comment: How are you planning to do this `I'm hoping that the code clears all previous input from the namespace:`

Comment: Well it overwrites the `age` variable hence clearing the previous input. However, its unclear what the person means by `namespace`. Do they mean remove the previous line in the cmd or start the process again